# Pegar o valor de um elemento span dinâmico

Tags: java, mvc, spring, thymeleaf

Preciso pegar um valor 'id' de um span dinâmico e não estou conseguindo. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Erro:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Required Long parameter 'id' is not present

View:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>CRUD</title>
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Edit or Delete User</h1>

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <td><span th:text=${user.id} name="id"></span></td>
        <td><span th:text=${user.name} name="name"></span></td>

    </table>


    <form action="../update" method="post">

        <div id="userEdit"></div>


        <div>
            <td><label for="userpassword">Password:</label> <input
                type="text" id="userpassword" name="user_password"></td>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>

    </form>

    <hr>

    <form action="deleteUser" method="post">
        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Método:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateUser(@RequestParam("id") Long id,
        @RequestParam("user_password") String newPassword) {

    User user = dao.find(id);
    User newUser = dao.find(user.getId());
    newUser.setPassword(newPassword);
    dao.save(newUser);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:crud");
}
```

Estou usando spring e thymeleaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O botão submit dentro de um `<form>` envia apenas os dados que estão dentro desse `<form>`. Logo, apenas o campo `user_password` vai ser enviado.

A solução é usar isso:

```html
    <form action="../update" method="post">

        <div id="userEdit"></div>

        <div>
            <label for="userpassword">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="userpassword" name="user_password" />
            <input type="hidden" value="${user.id}" name="id" />
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <hr>

    <form action="deleteUser" method="post">
        <div class="button">
            <input type="hidden" value="${user.id}" name="id" />
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Ou seja, a solução é colocar um `<input type="hidden" value="${user.id}" name="id" />` em cada `<form>`.

Além disso, eu tirei o `<td>` e o `</td>` do primeiro `<form>`, pois isso não faz sentido lá e acrescentei o `</div>` que faltava dentro do segundo `<form>`.

Além disso, recomendo usar o `method="delete"` no segundo `<form>` e então usar o `method = RequestMethod.DELETE` no lado do Java. O motivo disso é que o método DELETE é o método HTTP que foi criado justamente para deletar coisas.